# What's a pithy term to describe what a spy does when he/she socializes with a target to get information?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, terminology

I'm working on a roleplaying game, and I want a pithy name for a skill that modern intelligence agents call "elicitation of intelligence."  Setting is the interwar period in Europe (between WW I and WW II), and what I'm trying to describe is the act of having a seemingly casual conversation with a target, but subtly manipulating that conversation such that the target unknowingly reveals some secret information.  Most of the words and phrases I can think of are too general, and "elicitation" just sounds too 21st Century for a game set in the early 1920s.

P.S. - I apologize for the vague search tag.  Unfortunately, the site won't accept "1920s," "spy," "intelligence," or "espionage" at tags.

Comment: I've heard 'fishing' and 'fishing expedition' as general terms for information gathering. Pumping is more overt, so probably not what you want. You're looking for something like 'diplomacy' or 'persuasion' in most games, right? But more focused. I think "interrogation" is almost what you want, getting people to give you information they normally wouldn't. Except interrogation is too evocative of someone tied to a chair getting beat up. Manipulation?

Answer (score 29):

That spy is probably ***milking** for information*.

Cambridge:

> **[milk](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/milking)** *verb* (GET MONEY/INFORMATION)   [disapproving]
> to get as much money or information out of someone or something as possible,
> often in an unfair or dishonest way:
> The newspapers milked the story
> dry.

Example From Google Books:

> This was said as a question and I was convinced that she was
> **[milking for information](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Miss_Daisy_s_Diaries/q-CiiBzY_74C?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22milking+for+information%22&pg=PA129)**. [*Miss Daisy's Diaries* by Pamela Hunt]

Comment: Good answer but, since this is going to go in a game, @PandRNframe might wish to choose a different term given the modern slang usages of "milking".   (Unintended ribald hilarity may otherwise ensue)

Comment: In which case, and to continue the agricultural theme, how about "groom"?

Answer (score 13):

> the act of having a seemingly casual conversation with a target, but subtly manipulating that conversation such that the target unknowingly reveals some secret information.

This is known as "cultivating" - it continues until the other person is recruited or is of no further use.

It is an obvious extension of

OED

> **cultivate**, v. transitive. **To prepare and use (land) for growing crops; to improve and render fertile by husbandry;**

and is demonstrated in

> **6.b.** transitive. **To try to win the friendship or favour of (a person), now esp. with implications of flattery.**
>
> 1964 Because he was her brother I had cultivated him as a friend. *C.
> Chaplin, My Autobiography ix. 144*
>
> 2004 His contempt for journalists..did not prevent him from
> manipulating the media to his own ends, assiduously cultivating his
> influential contacts, [etc.]. *Times Literary Supplement 3 December
> 25/1*

Answer (score 8):

One possibility is *inveigle*, for which the OED includes:

> To draw (a person) by guile into (to, from, etc.) action, conduct, a place, etc.;

Answer (score 4):

"Elicitation" may be a more modern term used in the trade, but in the approximate era you mention "elicit information" was a perfectly acceptable term, though sadly not a single word.

Source: **How to Become a Spy**: The World War II SOE Training Manual
by British Special Operations Executive  Section C.2 *Opinion Sampling* dated September 1943:

> It is possible to elicit information without appearing to ask for it,
> to overhear gossip in cafes and queues, to observe behaviour in the
> group affected. This is proved by the fact that people have done it.

Answer (score 4):

### Plumb

Literally, to plumb something is to sink directly into the murky depths, like a plumb (lead) weight - an investigator intends to 'get to the bottom' of a conspiracy.

In a metaphorical sense, to [plumb](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/plumb-a-depth) someone for information is to elicit it, as you are asking for:

> VERB
> If you plumb something mysterious or difficult to understand, you succeed in understanding it. [...]
> [literary]
> to understand or master (something obscure)
> to plumb a mystery

It sets up a nice contrast between *plumbing* (extracting information surreptitiously) and *[pumping](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/620110/whats-a-pithy-term-to-describe-what-a-spy-does-when-he-she-socializes-with-a-ta/620174#comment1577144_620123)* (extracting information in a way that is obvious, such as interrogation or intimidation).

It connects to other 'information is water' metaphors; when an organization has secret information coming out that it does not want exposed, it has 'leaks' or 'leaky pipes'.  Nixon set up the [White House Plumbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_House_Plumbers) to try to stop the leaks that the Pentagon Papers represented.

Comment: This does indicate that one is uncovering information, but I don't get a connotation of subtlety or secrecy from it. I actually find it suggests the opposite - that one is going *straight to the bottom* of something in the most direct way possible. I would say this better describes what a police interrogator does to a suspect, rather than what a spy does to their target without them knowing.

Answer (score 2):

Finagle some information.

fi·na·gle
/fəˈnāɡ(ə)l/
verbinformal•US
verb: finagle; 3rd person present: finagles; past tense: finagled; past participle: finagled; gerund or present participle: finagling

```
obtain (something) by devious or dishonest means.
"Ted attended all the football games he could finagle tickets for"
    act in a devious or dishonest manner.
    "they wrangled and finagled over the fine points"
```

Answer (score 2):

If this is going to be a stat/ability like "charisma" or "stealth" or whatever, I would suggest **social engineering**.

This term is in current use for information security.  E.g. the current [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_engineering_(security))

> In the context of information security, social engineering is the psychological manipulation of people into performing actions or divulging confidential information.

The term can encompass a wide variety of techniques such as sweet-talking or outright seduction (a la Mata Hari), or a simple "pretending to be friends" scheme or one male baiting another into bragging about what they know, etc.

(The modern usage, btw, is usually around penetrating data security of some sort, such as tricking people into divulging passwords--like calling someone and pretending to be their manager's manager's manager and asking them for their password to fix an urgent database outage.  But I don't think that would hamper your usage of the term.)

I also looked up the [Google Books ngram search for the term](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%22social%20engineering%22&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) and their first use is contemporary with the time period you're talking about

Answer (score 1):

In an informal register, the idiom **butter up** fits:

> *butter up* ['phrasal verb' of butter] [informal]:
>
> flatter or praise someone as a means of gaining their help or support
>
> - "Don't try and butter me up in order to get privileged information."

[[Oxford Dictionary of English, courtesy of Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=butter+up+meaning&sca_esv=0dcc3d4151cae03d&rlz=1C1CHBF_en-GBGB973GB973&ei=MV3fZajtNpeDhbIP0MOOoAg&ved=0ahUKEwjoyaqeuM6EAxWXQUEAHdChA4QQ4dUDCBA&uact=5&oq=butter+up+meaning&gs_lp=Egxnd3Mtd2l6LXNlcnAiEWJ1dHRlciB1cCBtZWFuaW5nMgUQABiABDIGEAAYBxgeMgYQABgHGB4yBhAAGAcYHjIGEAAYBxgeMggQABgHGB4YDzIGEAAYBxgeMggQABgHGB4YDzIIEAAYBxgeGA8yCBAAGAcYHhgPSMYwUMIVWJEtcAF4AJABAJgBa6AB0QeqAQM5LjO4AQPIAQD4AQGYAg2gApYOwgIKEAAYRxjWBBiwA8ICDhAAGIAEGIoFGJECGLEDwgIKEAAYgAQYigUYQ8ICEBAAGIAEGIoFGJECGEYY-QHCAg0QABiABBiKBRhDGLEDwgIQEAAYgAQYigUYQxixAxiDAcICCxAAGIAEGIoFGJECwgIqEAAYgAQYigUYkQIYRhj5ARiXBRiMBRjdBBhGGPkBGPQDGPUDGPYD2AEBwgIIEAAYBxgeGArCAgcQABiABBgNmAMAiAYBkAYIugYGCAEQARgTkgcHOC40LjUtMQ&sclient=gws-wiz-serp)]

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/butter-up) indicates that flattery doesn't have to be involved:

> *butter someone up*
>
> to be very kind or friendly to someone or try to please someone, so
> that that person will do what you want them to do

Comment: This phrase could only be *restrictively* applied for situations which invariably involve flattery. One party smarms up to the other to wheedle information from them @Edwin Ashworth.

Comment: Not according to the Cambridge definition, 405.

Answer (score 1):

In general, this is "espionage", which is a word related to "spying".

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Espionage): "the act of obtaining secret or confidential information"

The wikipedia article contains other useful words such as "clandestine" (you might say "clandestine conversations for the purpose of gaining information". There is also "infiltration", meaning to obtain access to information by pretense, impersonation, etc.

I think you knew the word you were looking for all along.

Comment: -1 - this does not at all answer the question: _**what I'm trying to describe is the act of having a seemingly casual conversation with a target, but subtly manipulating that conversation such that the target unknowingly reveals some secret information**_  - 'espionage' is merely a general term which refers to obtaining information through spying, nor are any of the other suggestions relevant to the question.

Comment: Then it's "social engineering", I suppose.

Comment: 'espionage' could be considered a form of social engineering, but 'espionage' is a term with a specific meaning: _the discovering of secrets, especially political or military information of another country or the industrial information of a business_ : [**_espionage_**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/espionage)

Answer (score 1):

The OP is not writing a non-fiction novel but a role playing game; however, the following suggestion fits the main criterion requested: “a pithy name”

> ### snoop (verb.)
>
> **1832**, "go around in a prying manner," American English, probably from Dutch *snoepen* "to pry," also "eat in secret, eat sweets, sneak," which is probably related to *snappen* "to bite, snatch". The specific meaning "to pry into other people's business" is attested by 1921.

The following definition is dated **1894**

> **snoop**
> to pilfer in a crafty, sneaking manner; to mauraud with cunning

From an American newspaper dated **1935**

> Just now spy business is booming. Not since the World War have nations looked upon one another with more wholehearted distrust than at present and, consequently, they are spending more than ever before on their **snooping service**. Europe is employing an army of 100,000 spies this year at a cost estimated at $50,000,000.

The OP could call their secret [intelligence officer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intelligence_officer) colloquially a "snoop"

### snoop (noun)

> 1891, "act of snooping," from snoop (v.). **The U.S. colloquial meaning "one who snoops" is by 1902**; the sense of "detective" is from 1942. Snooper "one who pries or peeps" is from 1889.

Sources: [Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/snoop)
[The American Encyclopaedic Dictionary](https://www.google.it/books/edition/The_American_Encyclopaedic_Dictionary/pkV6F1UZytAC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22to%20pilfer%20in%20a%20crafty,%20sneaking%20manner%3B%20to%20mauraud%20with%20cunning%22&pg=PA3741&printsec=frontcover)
[Today An Independent National Weekly](https://https:/https://www.google.it/books/edition/Today/dJAoAQAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22their%20snoop-ing%20service%22&dq=%22their%20snoop-ing%20service%22&printsec=frontcover)

Answer (score 1):

The spy is **breadcrumbing** their target.

**Breadcrumb**

> To use clues or enticements to lead someone in the desired direction.

[*Wiktionary*]

Comment: I don't think this is applicable, the spy in question is trying to casually interrogate their subject so that the spy will gain information. Not guide the subject to a conclusion of the spy's choosing.

Comment: The OP mentions in the question... _the act of having a **seemingly casual** conversation with a target, but **subtly manipulating** that conversation such that the target unknowingly reveals some secret information._ I think *breadcrumbing* isn't totally off the mark, if not the exact word sought.

Answer (score 1):

**Chat up** :

Collins Concise English Dictionary © HarperCollins Publishers::
chat up
vb (tr, adverb) brit informal
***to talk persuasively to (a person), esp with an ulterior motive***

[***chat up***](https://www.wordreference.com/definition/chat%20up)

Although this is originally a British term, it has since trickled into American English, although it probably wasn't in use in the 1920's.

Answer (score 0):

To quote Inception: Extraction
As the verb "Extract":

> /ikˈstrakt/
> remove or take out, especially by effort or force.
> "the decayed tooth will have to be extracted"

I believe this would fit nicely. It has a ring to it. The spy extracts information. The spy performs extraction. The spy is extracting intel from the target.

Comment: I like the word, but in the context of spy stories I think of "Extraction" as a synonym for "Exfiltration". See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extraction_(military)

Comment: extracting information from someone is somewhat aggressive.

Answer (score 0):

Honeypotting: The honey pot or trap involves making contact with an individual who has information or resources required by a group or individual; the trapper will then seek to entice the target into a false relationship (which may or may not include actual physical involvement) in which they can glean information or influence over

Answer (score 0):

A typical term for so called psychics and mind readers is *Cold Reading* which involves locating people who may know something by *Reading the room* and then working on them to brag about secrets and details they would not expect you to make any sense of. Once you have them, suitably admired and puffed up they could spill everything they know just to get you in the sack.